# Is there any analog of django's forms in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, django-forms

Is there any analog of django's forms in Ruby on Rails?

Thanks,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the formtastic library (http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for some annotation based approach to automatically generate form according to its fields type or custom annotation which specify what template should be used to display certain field.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is something that generates administrative forms to CRUD records? [Here is a roundup of options](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/07/rails-admin-interface-roundup/), I've heard Typus recommended. If you have an internal application or basic form needs, these can be real timesavers.

Answer (score 0):

There are the [Rails Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). It's not exactly like django's forms but that would take out the fun of learning a new language and framework, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

there are https://trailblazer.to/2.1/docs/reform.html#reform-overview
Reform provides form objects to run validations for one or multiple models.